# Nuxt Error: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, strapi

I am attempting to deploy my Nuxt app to Netlify, but am receiving errors when `yarn run generate` is being run.

```
9:32:52 AM: $ yarn run generate
9:32:52 AM: yarn run v1.22.4
9:32:52 AM: $ nuxt generate
9:34:06 AM: [error] Could not resolve routes
9:34:06 AM: [fatal] Request failed with status code 403
9:34:06 AM:   at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
9:34:06 AM:   at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
9:34:06 AM:   at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
9:34:06 AM:   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
9:34:06 AM:   at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
9:34:06 AM:   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
9:34:06 AM:   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
9:34:06 AM: 
9:34:06 AM:    ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
9:34:06 AM:    │                                                │
9:34:06 AM:    │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                           │
9:34:06 AM:    │                                                │
9:34:06 AM:    │   Error: Request failed with status code 403   │
9:34:06 AM:    │                                                │
9:34:06 AM:    ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
9:34:06 AM: 
9:34:06 AM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
9:34:06 AM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
9:34:06 AM: ​
9:34:06 AM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
9:34:06 AM: │   "build.command" failed    │
9:34:06 AM: └─────────────────────────────┘
9:34:06 AM: ​
9:34:06 AM:   Error message
9:34:06 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn run generate
9:34:06 AM: ​
9:34:06 AM:   Error location
9:34:06 AM:   In Build command from settings:
9:34:06 AM:   yarn run generate
9:34:06 AM: ​
9:34:06 AM:   Resolved config
9:34:06 AM:   build:
9:34:06 AM:     base: /opt/build/repo
9:34:06 AM:     command: yarn run generate
9:34:06 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
9:34:06 AM: Caching artifacts
9:34:06 AM: Started saving node modules
9:34:06 AM: Finished saving node modules
9:34:06 AM: Started saving build plugins
9:34:06 AM: Finished saving build plugins
9:34:06 AM: Started saving yarn cache
9:34:06 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
9:34:06 AM: Started saving pip cache
9:34:14 AM: Finished saving pip cache
9:34:14 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
9:34:14 AM: Started saving go dependencies
9:34:16 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
9:34:16 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:34:16 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
9:34:16 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:34:16 AM: Finished processing build request in 2m4.577292784s
```

If I run `yarn run generate` locally, it works fine. I thought it had to do with the dynamic routes not being generated, but console logging everything locally, those dynamic routes appear to be generated correctly as well. I'm not entirely sure where to even begin with this error, because everything I've looked up seems unrelated or out of date.

The closest guess I have is that it's axios related in my `generateDynamicRoutes.js` file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.STRAPI_BACKEND_BASE,
});

const dynamicRoutes = async () => {

  // fetch galleries slugs
  const resForGalleries = await instance.get('/galleries');

  // fetch images slugs
  const resForImages = await instance.get('/images');

  const routesForGalleries = resForGalleries.data.map(gallery => {
    return {
      route: `/galleries/${gallery.slug}`,
      payload: gallery,
    };
  });

  const routesForImages = resForImages.data.map(image => {
    return {
      route: `/images/${image.slug}`,
      payload: image,
    };
  });

  return [...routesForGalleries, ...routesForImages];
};

export default dynamicRoutes;
```

*nuxt.config.js:*

```
import dynamicRoutes from './services/generateDynamicRoutes';

require('dotenv').config();

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  ...
  generate: {
    routes: dynamicRoutes
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

**Update:**
After some investigation, it appears to be because my Strapi backend doesn't have permissions set up yet in production for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the cors settings of my api (strapi) blocked the gitlab runner while `npm run generate`.

Answer (score 0):

### **Try Clearing Cookies**

Try clearing your browsers' cookies after a deployment, if you're trying to trace a mysterious 403.

I had multiple deploys (to Heroku) trying to trace a mysterious 403 for my Nuxt front-end (my proxy API routes still functioned all this time). None of my changes had any affect; I was spinning my wheels.

Randomly clearing my cookies and voila 403 cleared. In my case, there was auth middleware failing early on; fresh cookies reset the issue. I would have caught this much earlier if perhaps during my trials I tested in incognito (ie fresh cookies state).